# When are p-values deceptive?

Tags: bigdata, statistics

What are the data conditions that we should watch out for, where p-values may not be the best way of deciding statistical significance?  Are there specific problem types that fall into this category?

Comment: Snarky answer: almost always. There's a huge incentive to create Type 1 errors (i.e., "false alarms") when analysts examine data, so almost all p-values you'll encounter are "too" small.

Comment: Just throwing this out there, but wouldn't this sort of question best be posed on [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: @buruzaemon: Maybe.  I did a search, this is the closest match: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/67320/hypothesis-testing-with-big-data  There don't seem to be more than a handful of questions that touch on this.

Comment: goodness of fit (p value) measure of raw data and measure of difference between two statistics e.g. mean values - statistical significance are two different concepts.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are asking about [Data Dredging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_dredging), which is what happens when testing a very large number of hypotheses against a data set, or testing hypotheses against a data set that were suggested by the same data.

In particular, check out [Multiple hypothesis hazard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_comparisons), and [Testing hypotheses suggested by the data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Testing_hypotheses_suggested_by_the_data).

The solution is to use some kind of correction for [False discovery rate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_discovery_rate) or [Familywise error rate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Familywise_error_rate), such as [Scheffé's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheff%C3%A9%27s_method) or the (very old-school) [Bonferroni correction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonferroni_correction).

In a somewhat less rigorous way, it may help to filter your discoveries by the confidence interval for the odds ratio (OR) for each statistical result.  If the 99% confidence interval for the odds ratio is 10-12, then the OR is <= 1 with some *extremely* small probability, especially if the sample size is also large.  If you find something like this, it is probably a strong effect even if it came out of a test of millions of hypotheses.

Comment: While Bonferroni is definitely old-school it is still pretty popular. Related to it is a method called Šidák correction ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C5%A0id%C3%A1k_correction ). I am calling it out, because in a large scale targeting advertising system I worked on we were able to implement this approach as a UDF in Hive. However this only works better when you have independence between tests. If not you have to fall back to Bonferroni or another method.

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't consider the p-value out of context.

One rather basic point (as illustrated by [xkcd](http://xkcd.com/882/)) is that you need to consider how many tests you're actually doing.  Obviously, you shouldn't be shocked to see p < 0.05 for one out of 20 tests, even if the null hypothesis is true every time.

A more subtle example of this occurs in high-energy physics, and is known as the [look-elsewhere effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Look-elsewhere_effect).  The larger the parameter space you search for a signal that might represent a new particle, the more likely you are to see an apparent signal that's really just due to random fluctuations.

Answer (score 2):

One thing you should be aware of is the sample size you are using. Very large samples, such as economists using census data, will lead to deflated p-values. This paper ["Too Big to Fail: Large Samples and the p-Value Problem"](http://galitshmueli.com/system/files/Print%20Version.pdf) covers some of the issues.